# HAProxy and Radius

Tags: haproxy, radius

I've a following situation:

```
network1 - gate - network2
```

- network2 has several services.
- network1 has a lot of developers.

I need to make access from developers to services with separated access, for example:

- `dev1` should have access to debug ports on `host1` and `host2`,
- `dev2` should have access to debug portal on `host1` and `host3` and `host4`
- `dev3` should have access to http, debug and jmx ports on `host6`

So I need one authentication and authorization system for different services. HAProxy could work on TCP level, so I need in AA system, I think radius should be fine.

Is it possible to connect radius with haproxy and make accesses how I'd like to make them ?

Comment: Are you talking about using authentication in a HAProxy ACL, or to log onto the HAProxy box itself? Not entirely sure how haproxy fits into your network here.

Comment: I don't have HAProxy in my network yet, I'm searching for solution. So you could describe both options.

Comment: haproxy is unlikely to be suitable for what you want. haproxy is a load balancer. The only way you can reliably stop people from accessing ports on a different network is with a firewall, and it sounds like that's what you need here.

Comment: I'm using NAT now, but I don't what use it.
HAProxy has TCP balancer, so if someone go to somehost.local:specific_port could be redirected with HAProxy to someip:port, but I've read that HAProxy can do HTTP Auth, so we could combine it, but for http auth I need login:pass, which I think could be get from Radius.

Comment: Regarding the hostname part, someone else *just* asked the same thing: http://serverfault.com/q/740560/7709 - can't be done for most protocols. Yes haproxy can do TCP load balancing, but you're not using it for that, you're mostly just going to be using it for its ACLs. And you can't do http auth on anything except http itself, so you could just us a normal reverse proxy for the HTTP protocols. Something like nginx.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your only solution is a custom web application that, when a user logs in, it creates a temporary NAT rule for it (or allows the traffic to the NATted port temporarily).

Comment: The main idea - do not use NAT.